# opening another activity from the map overlay dialogs

Tags: android, android-maps

I am trying to create a map application and I need to do something similar to what Google Maps does.
I want to open show a list of locations and when user taps on them I want to show a dialog.

I was able to do it till here. But now when the user clicks on the dialog that opened I want to show another acttivity with the details of that item that they clicked on.

I tried to start a new intent but it gives me an error.

Here is what I am doing

```
private void drawPopupWindow(Canvas canvas,int index, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        GeoPoint geoPoint = item.getPoint();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        LinearLayout dialogLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_dialog, null);
        LayoutParams mapDialogParams = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                geoPoint, -1, -22, 
                LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        mapView.addView(dialogLayout, mapDialogParams);

        dialogLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent detailIntent = new Intent(mContext, ItemDetailView.class);
                mContext.startActivity(detailIntent); // I passed the context from mapActivity
            }
        });     

    }
```

Here is the stack trace

```
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
> start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.achie.test.mapssample/com.achie.test.mapssample.ItemDetailView}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary
> XML file line #2: Error inflating
> class <unknown> E/AndroidRuntime(
> 4985):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):
> Caused by:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary
> XML file line #2: Error inflating
> class <unknown> E/AndroidRuntime(
> 4985):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.achie.test.mapssample.ItemDetailView.onCreate(ItemDetailView.java:11)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  ... 11 more
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:238)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  ... 20 more
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985): Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> MapViews can only be created inside
> instances of MapActivity.
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:282)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  at
> com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 4985):  ... 24 more
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve this and open a new activity?

Also where can I find the source code for the google maps on android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the stack trace tells you, "MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity." You are attempting to create a `MapView` outside of a `MapActivity`. Change your code to avoid doing this, and you will clear up this error.